# "Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: mail" , but I get nothing

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, xampp

I use Xampp and I want to send an email using CodeIgniter. If using smtp get error:

> Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to
>   ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Unable to find the socket transport
>   "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?)
>   Filename: libraries/Email.php

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'gmail@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => 'your_password'
);

$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");   
$this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('(here I put my mail)@yahoo.com');
$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');
$this->email->send();
echo $this->email->print_debugger();

(line extension=php_openssl.dll is decomented)
```

With these settings:

```
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");   
$this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('(here I put my mail)@yahoo.com');
$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');
$this->email->send();
echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

appears message:Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: mail

From: "Your Name" 
Return-Path:.......

but I get nothing mail.

What is the problem?

Comment: Sounds like you need yourself a mail server. p.s. if youre going to downvote something, comment and tell why. upvoting until then.

Comment: @Nick that's not how voting is supposed to work. Please don't upvote stuff just to offset other people's downvotes.

Comment: @Pekka웃 If someones not going to explain why they downvoted, as they should, then i see no reason to ruin someones reputaton. they could at least be told how to improve.  The upvote is not without reason

Comment: You can't send E-Mail with a "from" address that doesn't have to do with the server you're sending from. That's bound to end up your message in a spam filter.

Comment: Also, try removing `ssl://` from the smtp_host line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to throw in my little bit:

---

On your first example using gmail. If you just had line extension=php_openssl.dll  decommented, you might have to restart apache before testing. Especially if you are using a windows system. That was exactly how I fixed mine. Check your phpinfo() to ensure that you have ssl support for your php version. Assuming you are using xampp, that should be there.

I also recommend that the FROM email be a gmail account. Possibly same as was used in smtp_user. You can always include other email info you desire in the message. If I intend to reply the sender, instead of using the sender's email as from, I use a gmail account. In the body of the message, I could include a mailto link with subject same as message subject. For example:

```
<a href="mail:email@stewardxpress.com?subject=From The User's Form" >Reply User</a>
```

When the mail to link is click, I get to reply easily with Outlook or Gmail. It might be a bit windy but it works and prevents my mails ending up in spam folders

---

On your second example, that won't work in localhost. So I guess you are using a web hosting account. Some host would require that you specify the smtp server, username and password to be used in the from field. Most common smtp would be smtp.example.com. The IP does work too, try pinging to get the smtp IP (Note that for some reasons, this might change). Include those and give it a try.

---

In addition to the above,
Check the catchall email configured in the server to see if the email ever arrived. Trying sending to yourself. Check spam and junk folders. The mail has left you successfully and could possibly be queued for later delivery. Some sort of server refresh might be required.

Answer (score 2):

1. 'mail' protocol means it's using PHP's `mail()` function that simply submits to the server's mail agent. 'Success' simply means that it was accepted, but does not indicate if it was ever even attempted to be delivered. The mail agent could be turned off, misconfigured, etc, etc. You'll need to check the mail logs or, more likely, ask your hosting provider.
2. If you're actually using the 'from' address of `anything@example.com` I doubt that the mail will ever actually go through. Use a real email address that can receive email itself.
3. Check your spam folder.